# Why do I get "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, dyld

I am trying to use a cocoapod https://cocoapods.org/pods/smart-view-sdk which is a swift framwith my objective-c app but I get below error message at runtime.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ankita/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/98F1A80B-F6D8-474C-8692-A5013E2F0610/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4E7D4611-C4E7-4F60-9989-8BBAE3FA3F38/HelloWorld_ObjectiveC.app/Frameworks/SmartView.framework/SmartView
  Reason: image not found
```

Pod works well with Swift project. It also works good when I manually embed it rather thru Pod for both Swift and Obj-C sample apps.

I think, I have not left any links or discussion forums to  fix this, but yet I get this annoying error.

Following changes that I tried but failed to work:

- Target | Build Settings | "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to Yes
- Project | Build Settings | "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to Yes
- "Build Settings | Search Paths | * <- tried all suggestions
- Tried with Apple Developer Certificate suggestions
- Tried all suggestions for Build Phases

I am using Xcode 8.3.
Any help.

Comment: I faced this problem while embedding `Evernote SDK` , I solved by adding it to **General -> Embedded Binaries**  . You can try it .

Comment: If you install SDK by Pod, framework is added directly. Tried adding manually as well and failed with same error